# Oracle sql to find out organizations with null parents

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table `PER_ORG_STRUCTURE_ELEMENTS` which has `parent_id` of  an organization as well as the `child_id`. I want all those organizations whose parent organization is not defined.

The query I am using to fetch the parent organization is:

```
SELECT
org.organization_id parent_id,
org.name parent_name,
pose.organization_id_child,
(select name from hr_all_organization_units
where organization_id=pose.organization_id_child) child
FROM
hr_all_organization_units org,
per_org_structure_elements pose
WHERE 1=1
AND org.organization_id = pose.organization_id_parent(+)
--and organization_id_child=246
AND pose.org_structure_version_id = 61;
```

But through this I am getting those organizations whose parent organization has been defined.

```
per_org_structure_elements has org_parent_id,org_child_id,org_structure_version_id  as columns
and hr_organization_units has org_id,name as columns
```

Comment: If it is possible, could you please include sample data in the question?

Comment: You can't get the the results you want.. The best you could get is the children pointed to a parent record that doesn't exist.  Since the parent doesn't exist you can't list the parent organization...

Comment: Thank you for posting the table structure. Do you have data that you can post as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Select aou.* 
From Hr_all_organization_units aou, per_org_structure_elements ose
where aou.organization_id = ose.organization_id
And ose.organization_id_parent is null
```

Comment: Not working.per_org_structure_elements  has parent_id and child_id no organization_id

Answer (score 0):

Try this RIGHT OUTER JOIN:

**EDIT**:

Here's the modified query to query within the `PER_ORG_STRUCTURE_ELEMENTS` table for missing parent entry.

```
SELECT POSE_CHILD.*
FROM PER_ORG_STRUCTURE_ELEMENTS POSE_PARENT
RIGHT OUTER JOIN
PER_ORG_STRUCTURE_ELEMENTS POSE_CHILD
ON POSE_CHILD.ORGANIZATION_ID_PARENT=POSE_PARENT.ORGANIZATION_ID_CHILD
WHERE POSE_PARENT.ORGANIZATION_ID_CHILD IS NULL
AND POSE_CHILD.ORG_STRUCTURE_VERSION_ID = 61;
```

Comment: HAOU.ORGANIZATION_ID  cannot be null.....
actually when thr is no parent_id in PER_ORG_STRUCTURE_ELEMENTS there is no entry in PER_ORG_STRUCTURE_ELEMENTS . Can i use union ? not getting any idea how to go abt it ?

Comment: ah, then the check needs to be the other way around. The parent is defined in HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS but not in the PER_ORG_STRUCTURE_ELEMENTS table, right?

Comment: see HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS  has all the organizations in the form of organization_id i.e child_id and parent_id but the PER_ORG_STRUCTURE_ELEMENTS  contains the  relationship between the child and parent. So there might be organizations which do not have parent organizations.... that has to be fetched

Comment: @sonakshisinha What do you mean by "there might be organizations which do not have parent organizations". Would POSE.ORGANIZATION_ID_PARENT be NULL? In that case, can you query SELECT * FROM PER_ORG_STRUCTURE_ELEMENTS WHERE POSE.ORGANIZATION_ID_PARENT IS NULL;?

Comment: No there might be organization which exist in HR_ALL_ORGANIZATION_UNITS  but will not have  parent organization.so will not have a row in PER_ORG_STRUCTURE_ELEMENTS  itself

Comment: ok, so from what I understand, the child organization in in POSE does not have an entry for its parent in POSE itself. You want to find these records. If so, I have modified the query above.

Comment: I am so srry this will also not work as parent_id cannot be equal to child_id

Comment: I thought that the table has hierarchical data within it (The child_id of one row is the parent_id of another row). Or is there just an id column in the POSE table? Could you please include some sample table of the tables in your question? It would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Pose.Organization_ID_Parent
FROM hr_all_organization_units org
RIGHT JOIN per_org_structure_elements pose
 on org.organization_id = pose.organization_id_parent
where  Pose.Organization_ID_Parent is null
 and POSE.ORG_STRUCTURE_VERSION_ID = 61;
```